# Finding a file on ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm using the command :

```sh
find / -name "jsonutils*"
```

to find the path of file `jsonutils*`. I could find the path but in addition to that my output looked like (part of my output):

```
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-systemd-timesyncd.service-tA2YPA’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-ModemManager.service-bDilr5’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-systemd-resolved.service-Xor7fl’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-apache2.service-PecTo4’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-colord.service-jryVNf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-dell-linux-assistant.service-zXBhBb’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-bolt.service-XFK4Ri’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/tmp/systemd-private-e5ababe0e5984e3bb45fb0b411ee3b7e-rtkit-daemon.service-lBdVcg’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/spool/cups’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/spool/rsyslog’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/spool/cron/crontabs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/log/elasticsearch’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/log/speech-dispatcher’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/log/gdm3’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/elasticsearch’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/polkit-1’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/colord/.cache’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/fwupd/gnupg’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/snapd/cookie’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/snapd/cache’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/snapd/void’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/udisks2’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.config/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.config/gnome-session’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.config/ibus’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.gnupg’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.cache/libgweather’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/gdm3/.local’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql-files’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql-keyring’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/zerotier-one/controller.d’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/bluetooth/28:CD:C4:06:9E:70’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/geoclue/.cache’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/cups’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/partial’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1598572800’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1598313600’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1600646400’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1599004800’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1598832000’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/dell-telemetry/1600041600’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/ldconfig’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core18/1885/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core18/1885/root’: Permission denied
```

I want to suppress this and get only the pathname. Could someone guide me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to suppress "Permission denied" messages. You can redirect errors to /dev/null:

```
find / -name "jsonutils*" 2>/dev/null
```